# How to handle sync browser emulations in node.js

Tags: node.js, browser, emulation, nightmare

I'm writing a script that is intended to load some stuff from .txt files and then perform multiple ( in a loop) requests to a website with node.js` browser emulator nightmare.

I have no problem with reading from the txt files and so no, but managing to make it run sync and without exceptions.

```
function visitPage(url, code) {
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Nightmare
      .goto(url)
      .click('.vote')
              .insert('input[name=username]', 'testadmin')
              .insert('.test-code-verify', code)
      .click('.button.vote.submit')
      .wait('.tag.vote.disabled,.validation-error')
      .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.validation -error').innerHTML)
      .end()
      .then(text => {
          return text;
      })
});
}


async function myBackEndLogic() {
try {
    var br = 0, user, proxy, current, agent;


    while(br < loops){

        current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLoops-br-1));

        /*...getting user and so on..*/




        const response = await visitPage('https://example.com/admin/login',"code")

        br++;
    }


} catch (error) {
    console.error('ERROR:');
    console.error(error);
}
}

myBackEndLogic();
```

The error that occurs is:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'webContents' of undefined

So the questions are a few:

1) How to fix the exception

2) How to make it actually work sync and emulate everytime the address ( as in a previous attempt, which I didn't save, I fixed the exception, but the browser wasn't actually openning and it was basically skipped

3) (Not so important) Is it possible to select a few objects with

```
.wait('.class1,.class2,.validation-error')
```

and save each value in different variables or just get the text from the first that occured? ( if no any of these has occurred, then return 0 for example )

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with the code above.

1. In the `visitPage` function, you are returning a Promise.  That's fine, except you don't have to create the wrapping promise!  It looks like nightmare returns a promise for you.  Today, you're dropping an errors that promise returns by wrapping it.  Instead - just use an async function!

```
async function visitPage(url, code) {
  return Nightmare
      .goto(url)
      .click('.vote')
              .insert('input[name=username]', 'testadmin')
              .insert('.test-code-verify', code)
      .click('.button.vote.submit')
      .wait('.tag.vote.disabled,.validation-error')
      .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.validation -error').innerHTML)
      .end();
}
```

2. You probably don't want to wrap the content of this method in a 'try/catch'.  Just let the promises flow :)

```
async function myBackEndLogic() {
  var br = 0, user, proxy, current, agent;
  while(br < loops){
    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLoops-br-1));
    const response = await visitPage('https://example.com/admin/login',"code")
    br++;
  }
}
```

3. When you run your method - make sure to include a catch!  Or a then!  Otherwise, your app may exit early.

```
myBackEndLogic()
  .then(() => console.log('donesies!'))
  .catch(console.error);
```

I'm not sure if any of this will help with your specific issue, but hopefully it gets you on the right path :)

Comment: just wanted to note that you don't need `async function` in visitPage since Nightmare already returns a promise